# MIMIC-III Elixhauser comorbidity table

Tags: mimic-iii

How can I obtain a table containing the 30 Elixhauser comorbidities for patients in the MIMIC-III database? Did anybody already run the code in the MIMIC-III forum?

Answer (score 4):

Code for deriving an Elixhauser comorbidity table for the MIMIC-III Critical Care Database has been developed by Alistair Johnson and shared via the [MIMIC Code Repository](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/). The repository can be found by following the "Code" link on the front page of the [MIMIC website](http://mimic.physionet.org/).

Comment: Direct link for [MySQL](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/comorbidity/mysql/4-elixhauser.sql) and [Postgres](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/comorbidity/postgres/elixhauser.sql).

Comment: Important to note that MIMIC does not provide "present on admission" identifiers for these diagnosis codes, which limits the accuracy of the derived Elixhauser score.